# Как правильно настроить htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть два файла: `index.php` и `new.php`.

Нужно, чтобы при вводе любого текста после домена (`domain.ru/tuttext`) открывался `index.php?url=tuttext`

Я это сделал так

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Все работает, но теперь нужно добавить адрес domain.ru/new/tuttext и чтобы он открывал файл new.php?url=tuttext

Пробовал так

```
RewriteRule ^new/(.*)$ new.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Но при переходе на `domain.ru/new/text` загружается файл `index.php`

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=$1
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://site.ru/new.php?url=tuttext? [R=301,L]
```

Или что там у вас и как сортировка по условию на текст - вставьте нужное, так, вроде:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://site.ru/new.php?url=tuttext? [R=301,L]
```